# Trying to use mysqldump and cron on one db with password

Tags: mysql, cron

New to this!
I try to take a mysqldump using cron but dont know how to do it.
2 problems. How do I add the passwd in the script?
And how do I set the folder where the db_backup should be stored

Today I do it manually but want to automate it

I use this manually from the folder where the db should be stored and it works perfect

`mysqldump -u jv74 -p  db_jv74 > db_jv74_bk.sql`

Answer (score 1):

For the password problem, do this: create a file `/home/jv74/.my.cnf` with these contents:

```
   [client]
   user=myuser
   password=mypassword
```

Give it the proper permissions:

```
chmod 600 /home/jv74/.my.cnf
```

This should stop `mysql` (and `mysqldump`) from asking for your password. When run by `cron` you need to explicitly point to the option file:

```
mysqldump --defaults-file=/home/jv74/.my.cnf
```

As for the redirection to the proper folder, specify the full path:

```
mysqldump --defaults-file=/home/jv74/.my.cnf db_jv74 > /path/to/folder/dv_jv74_bk.sql
```

Comment: THANKS! That worked flawless. Will now test with cron also